# If $f$ is $C^1$ s. t. $\Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert \geq k \Vert x - y \Vert$, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function-theorem

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a function of class $C^1$ and suppose that there is $k>0$ such that
>   $$\Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert \geq k \Vert x - y \Vert$$
>   for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
>
> (a) Prove that $f$ is injective and $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is closed.
>
> (b) Prove that $f'$ is invertible.
>
> (c) Prove that $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is open. Conclude that $f$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**My attempt.**

(a) If $f(x) = f(y)$, then $\Vert x - y \Vert = 0$, that is, $x=y$. Take $(f(x_{n}))$ such that $f(x_{n}) \to p$. By hypothesis, $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy and by continuity, $f(x_{n}) \to f(q) = p$ where $x_{n} \to q$. Thus, $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is closed.

---

(b) I dont know how to prove.

---

(c) I proved in a previous question that

> if $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $C^1$ with $\det Df \neq 0$, then $f$ is an open map.

Suppose (b), $f$ is an open map and, therefore, $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is open. So, $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is non-empty clopen set, that is, $f(\mathbb{R}^{n}) = \mathbb{R}^{n}$. By Inverse Function Theorem, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Note that $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bijective and, since $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, $f^{-1}$ is differentiable for each $x$. Then $f$ is a $C^1$ diffeormorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

---

Is (a) and (c) corrects? I need help with item (b).

Comment: Parts (a) and (c) look good.  Re part (b), the question should probably say to prove that $Df$ is invertible.

Comment: For part (b), what if there is a point $x$ so that $Df(x)$ is not invertible?

Comment: If $Df$ is not invertible for some $x$, there is a unity vector $v$ such that $D_{x}f(v) = 0$. But, $D_{x}f(v) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\Vert f(x+tv) - f(x)\Vert}{|t|} = 0$, that is, for $\epsilon >0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|t|<\delta$ implies $\Vert f(x+tv) - f(x)\Vert < k|t|  = k\Vert tv \Vert = k\Vert x+tv - x$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\{0 \}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then by definition of $Df(x_0)$
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\Vert{f(x_0+ty)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)\cdot ty}\Vert}{\Vert ty\Vert}=0$$
Then:

$$\frac{\Vert{f(x_0+ty)-f(x_0)-Df\cdot ty}\Vert}{\Vert ty\Vert}\geq\frac{\Vert{f(x_0+ty)-f(x_0)\Vert-\Vert Df(x_0)\cdot ty}\Vert}{\Vert ty\Vert}\geq \frac{k\Vert ty \Vert-\Vert Df(x_0)\cdot ty\Vert}{\Vert ty \Vert}=k-\frac{\Vert Df(x_0) \cdot y \Vert}{\Vert y \Vert}$$

This leads to:
$$0=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\Vert{f(x_0+ty)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)\cdot ty}\Vert}{\Vert ty\Vert}\geq\lim_{t\rightarrow0}k-\frac{\Vert Df(x_0) \cdot y \Vert}{\Vert y \Vert}=k-\frac{\Vert Df(x_0) \cdot y \Vert}{\Vert y \Vert}$$
$$\Rightarrow \Vert Df(x_0) \cdot y \Vert\geq k \Vert y \Vert >0$$

So $Df(x_0)$ is invertible.

(b) and (c) are correct.